# CAnt call balanceOf nft

Tags: web3js, javascript, ethers.js, ethereumjs, react

```
const checkBalanceOf = () => {
  Web3EthContract.setProvider("https://goerli.infura.io/v3/bafa2a1c83d44b099dcae3a32b54207b");
  let web3 = new Web3("https://goerli.infura.io/v3/bafa2a1c83d44b099dcae3a32b54207b");
  let abi = [//i put contract abi here.];
  const SmartContract= new Web3EthContract(
    abi,
   '0xB210Bb5Db833D514Dea25B1C78a2317F759327AE'
  );
  SmartContract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call()
  .then((receipt) => {
    console.log("NFTs:", receipt);
    setTotalBalance(receipt);
   
  
    });
  };
```

//this works just fine on BSC. i must be doing something wrong that has to do with eth? anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

Here is the code you need to call `balanceOf` using `web3.js`.

> Also, be careful because you posted your Infura API key in your question. Make sure to delete that node and make another one, and never post API keys online :)

The following code works on either the BNB chain or Ethereum.

This specific example retrieves the balance of [Mutant Ape Yacht Club](https://etherscan.io/address/0x60e4d786628fea6478f785a6d7e704777c86a7c6) (on mainnet) from [an address](https://etherscan.io/address/0xaa621b960f22911462550c078df678493c22b2ae) holding 53 of them.

```js
// Address to check the balance from.
const walletAddress = "0xaa621b960f22911462550c078df678493c22b2ae"

const checkBalanceOf = () => {
  // Create a provider instance
  const node_url ="YOUR_NODE_URL";
  const web3 = new Web3(node_url);

  // Create a smart contract instance
  const abi = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"_name","type":"string"},{"internalType":"string","name":"_symbol","type":"string"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_maxSupply","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"approved","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"ApprovalForAll","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Lock","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"NonFungibleTokenRecovery","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"TokenRecovery","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"baseURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getApproved","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"isApprovedForAll","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"isLocked","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"lock","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"maxSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"recoverNonFungibleToken","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_token","type":"address"}],"name":"recoverToken","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"setApprovalForAll","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"_uri","type":"string"}],"name":"setBaseURI","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"index","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenByIndex","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"index","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenOfOwnerByIndex","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"cursor","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"size","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokensOfOwnerBySize","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}];
  const contractAddress = "0x60E4d786628Fea6478F785A6d7e704777c86a7c6"
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress)

  // call a view/pure function
  contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call(function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("An error occured", err)
      return
    }
    console.log(`The balance is: ${res}`)
  })
}
```

When you run it you will receive this respose:

```sh
The balance is: 53
```

Just change the `walletAddress` and `contractAddress` constants to query a different address from a different NFT contract.